# What does the full scale range in a IMU MPU9250 datasheet signify?

Tags: sensor, imu

I have MPU9250 IMU, which I am working on to get orientations from the sensor output data. While exploring the MPU9250 (also other sensor such as BNO055) datasheet I came across the full scale range for accel & gyro given as `±2 ±4 ±8 ±16 (g)` and `±250 ±500 ±1000 ±2000 (deg/s)`. I did not understand what it signifies, but seems important.

I tried searching online related to full scale range but did not get explanation regarding it. I request if someone could help me in understanding by providing good explanation or a source which I can go through, I'd really appreciate that.

Also which one would be better to use?

I have asked the same question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191547/what-does-the-full-scale-range-in-a-imu-mpu9250-datasheet-signify-and-which-is-b). I really need help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR:

The configurable scale ranges for the accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer on the MPU-9250 IMU affect the maximum resolution and range of the reported values.

As you increase the full-scale range setting, the maximum value/rate that can be reported by the IMU before the IMU is saturated increases, but the resolution of the value/rate decreases.

---

Section 3.1 of the [datasheet for the Invensense MPU-9250](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) has a table that states the "*Gyroscope ADC Word Length*", which represents how large the values reported over the I<sup>2</sup>C or SPI interfaces are. In this case, the gyro word length is 16 bits. A 16 bit two's complement binary number (*explained wonderfully in [this video by Ben Eater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE)*) can range from -32768 to +32767.

[image]

Take the example of the ±500 °/s full-scale range. The unit resolution of the two's complement value reported by the gyro (*aka Least Significant Bit/LSB resolution*) in the ±500 °/s full-scale range is: $\frac{32767}{500} = 65.534$ LSB/(°/s) (*degrees per second per LSB*). This is not coincidentally labeled in the graph as the "*Sensitivity Scale Factor*" for the `FS_SEL=1` condition.

Comment: Thank you @ifconfig for giving a detailed explanation. I did not know full scale range and sensitivity are dependent. Also does that mean a reading of sensitivity 65.534 LSB/(°/s)  equals 1 rotation, if I have my full scale selected as 500 °/s ?

Comment: No, @TheLazy. `Actual Gyro Rate = Sensor Value * Sensitivity Scale Factor`, so one full rotation, or 360°/s, translates into a sensor value equaling `360 °/s / 65.534 LSB/(°/s) = 5.49`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score 5):

The full scale range is the largest value that the sensor can report; this is usually a balance of sensitivity to word length. If you have 8 bits to report the value, how many deg/s do you make one bit? The more deg/s you use per bit, you can report a bigger full-scale value but you loose sensitivity as the minimum change reported increases.

As an example, think of a car speedometer which can only show 2 digits. The full scale range would be ±99 kph - it cannot tell you if you are doing 100+, even if you are.
However, this 2-digit display could show `speed / 10` instead; it can now show up to **99**9 kph, but you cannot tell if you are doing **12**6 or **12**9 as you have decreased the resolution to increase the full scale range.

Comment: This was great. thanks a lot